# dbms mini project-Insert data

Tags: netbeans-8

I am working on a mini project of dbms for my academics, i have written below code to insert the detail, but when i click insert its not taking. i dont see any errors as well.. please help on this.

Netbeans and runsql command line are used..

```
 try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
       String t_id = tid.getText();
        String tname = tnamme.getText();
       String quali = qualifi.getText();
      String  phn_no=phn.getText();
      String  gender = gendr.getText();
      String  bdate = birth.getText();
      String address=addr.getText();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@VAIO:1521:xe","system","system");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate("insert into staff1 values('"+t_id+"','"+tname+"','"+quali+"','"+phn_no+"','"+gender+"','"+bdate+"','"+address+"')");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Inserted Successfully!!" );
        tid.setText("");
        tnamme.setText("");
        qualifi.setText("");
        phn.setText("");
        gendr.setText("");
        birth.setText("");
        addr.setText("");
        st.close();
        conn.close();
    }catch( ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```